Issue with Rate Limiting for POST Requests in Spring Cloud Gateway ( Authentication Problem with rate limiting fine without it )
I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application that handles both GET and POST requests. The gateway is configured to use rate limiting for both types of requests. However, while rate limiting works fine for GET requests, it causes POST requests to be forbidden by the gateway itself.
Configuration Details
Gateway Configuration (application.yml):
management:
  health:
    redis:
      enabled: true

spring:
  application:
    name: Gateway
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: productserviceforwarding
          predicates:
            - Path=/products/**
            - Method=GET
          uri: lb://productservice
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1

        - id: productserviceforwarding-post
          predicates:
            - Path=/products/**
            - Method=POST
          uri: lb://productservice
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: my-provider
            client-id: GW2
            client-secret: GW2Secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:500/login/oauth2/code/gateway"
        provider:
          my-provider:
            issuer-uri: "http://localhost:2000"
            authorization-uri: "http://localhost:2000/oauth2/authorize"
            token-uri: "http://localhost:2000/oauth2/token"
  data:
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 6379

server:
  port: 500

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9000/eureka

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit: DEBUG
    org.springframework.data.redis: DEBUG

Security Configuration (SecurityConfig.java):
package com.example.gateway.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(authorize -> authorize
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/products/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/products/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/products/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/products/**").authenticated()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Gateway</name>
    <description>Gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Problem Description

GET Requests: Rate limiting works as expected.

POST Requests: When rate limiting is disabled, POST requests are sent directly to the resource server. However, when rate limiting is enabled, the requests are forbidden by the gateway itself.

That adding Rate limiting in application should not impact the authentication flow

This is getting true in GET REQUEST NOT IN POST REQUEST




You are sending requests to an application withoauth2Login. Such requests are authorized with a session cookie, not a Bearer token. Also, as the Gateway security is based on session cookies, it is vulnerable to CSRF attacks. You should ALWAYS keep protection against CSRF enabled in security filter-chain withoauth2Login..

I have resolved the issue with rate limiting for POST requests in my Spring Cloud Gateway application. The problem was that rate limiting requires an identifier for the entity accessing the gateway. For authenticated requests, this identifier is provided automatically. However, for POST requests without authentication, the gateway lacks this identifier and consequently blocks the requests.
I am doing this on testing hence I have disabled the csrf , outh2Login is been used for the get requests which are working fine  for the post requests the request comes with the bearer token

Adding these have resolved my error
@Bean
public KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
return exchange -> Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
}
and
spring:
cloud:
gateway:
default-filters:
- TokenRelay=
- name: RequestRateLimiter
args:
key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1

I have resolved the issue with rate limiting for POST requests in my Spring Cloud Gateway application. The problem was that rate limiting requires an identifier for the entity accessing the gateway. For authenticated requests, this identifier is provided automatically. However, for POST requests without authentication, the gateway lacks this identifier and consequently blocks the requests.
Implement Custom KeyResolver
@Bean
public KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
    return exchange -> Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
}

Then specify the KeyResolver in your configuration:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
          args:
            key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
            redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
            redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1

